# Fitting webview on screen without access to webpage code

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

Okay, I have a webview and I am trying to load this url: http://catalog.ccbcmd.edu/preview_course_incoming.php?catname=Catalog%202015-16&prefix=ENGL&code=101

I don't have access to any of the page's source code to edit it. I want to format the webview so that views don't have to scroll horizontally, but, when I get it all to fit on the screen it's too small. Can somebody help? I would be okay with a vertical scrollbar if it's needed.

UPDATE: Here is my code

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollContainer(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);      
    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

[image: Good text size, but has horizontal scrollbar]
[image: No vertical scrollbar, but really small text]

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable Zoom.

webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Like that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using text autosizing, it will automatically enlarge your text.It works on KITKAT and above.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    browser.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
}
```